# Get progress of a file being downloaded from google drive using Google Drive API v3

Tags: java

I'm using this code to download a file from Google Drive:

```
        Drive.Files.Get get = SERVICE.files().get(file.getId());
        get.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new ProgressListener());
        get.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
        
        get.getMediaHttpDownloader().setChunkSize(1000000);
```

I want to download a file about 10 MB and i want to track the progress.
When i run my code it always shows "0.0" and after the download finished it shows "1.0" in the console.

My listener:

```
public class ProgressListener implements MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener {

public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) {
    switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
            System.out.println(downloader.getProgress());
            break;
        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
            System.out.println("Download is complete!");
    }
}
```

I only get updates like every 10 seconds..., but then the download is already finished

Pls help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using chunked upload/download (direct download on false) the api uploads the file in chunk in sized defined by the dev.

Each time a chunk is sent/recieved the progrss listener updates and in your case runs the block that matches its state.

This means that having a chunk size of 1_000_000 means that every chunk is made of 1 MB and this is the probable cause of the slow refresh rate.